# Does a statute of limitation apply to Virginia's mask law?

Tags: virginia

Virginia [§ 18.2-422](https://law.lis.virginia.gov/vacode/title18.2/chapter9/section18.2-422/) makes wearing a KKK hood or other face covering a felony, both in public, and in private unless it is with the owner's written permission.

Could someone ([not mentioning any names](https://www.washingtonpost.com/history/2019/02/02/northams-ugly-yearbook-photo-racist-origins-blackface/?utm_term=.59776ce533b6)) still be prosecuted for violating this law in the 1980s?

(Also, if it matters, the "with the intent to conceal his identity" clause was recently added. That phrase was absent in the 1980s.)

Comment: The law you quote has an exception for with permission of owner of private party, though presumably he did not have *written* permission, and if it was a rental (they were students), the host was not the owner. But it also has exceptions for holiday costumes and masquerade balls. Presumably this was a Halloween party and not a "reenact the era of lynching" party. Without answering the title questions (hence this is a comment), I think a hypothetical person found to be in a photo wearing a hood and standing next to a minstrel character and holding a beer would be OK from this law..

Comment: @Damila according to this https://virginia.ourcommunitynow.com/news/halloween-virginia-mask-law/ it might still be illegal even if it is a Halloween party.

Comment: @DavePhD one could presumably provide a defense by wearing a name tag in addition to the mask.

Comment: @Damila also: http://www.nbc29.com/story/11419913/halloween-mask-warning

Comment: @DavePhD Interesting, though that is the opinion of the blogger- what of a party in late October but not October 31? I wonder if there has ever been a case tried. The example of the skateboarder and Batman is in public, not at a party and not so close to Oct. 31. Also, one correction to my earlier comment, private property requires permission of the owner or tenant (not just the owner) but still it has to be written.

Comment: @DavePhD it's also worth noting that the first news story says that the Halloween masks would fall afoul of the law if they are worn on the weekend, because Halloween falls on Tuesday.  But the law does not provide an exception for masks worn *on a holiday* (and AFAIK Halloween isn't a legal holiday in Virginia anyway).  The exception is for "persons wearing traditional holiday costumes."  A Halloween costume worn on the Saturday before Halloween is still a Halloween costume.

Comment: @DavePhD The second news story specifically advises to keep it off until you get to the party.

Comment: @Damila  The party could fall under the "masquerade ball" exception.  What about wearing blackface at a Michael Jackson dance contest (if it wasn't near Halloween)?  Would that be a "bona fide theatrical production"?

Comment: @DavePhD That is my point- the picture was at some sort of party. And I thought the dance contest was in Texas. I mean, if we were talking about anyone real of course ;)

Comment: @Damila Good points.

Comment: I seriously doubt that "blackface" is a mask.  As I understand it, it is just makeup.  Are we going to prosecute people for putting on too much makeup?

Comment: @emory Jeremy Putnam got arrested and charged with the felony just for wearing make-up.  https://io9.gizmodo.com/man-in-joker-makeup-charged-with-felony-for-wearing-mas-1793638966  I'll try to find if he was convicted.

Comment: @emory charges were dropped https://www.localdvm.com/news/nova/a-man-dressed-as-the-joker-was-arrested-in-winchester/680706153

Comment: @DavePhD Interesting, how come orange face still walks free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virginia's "limitation of prosecutions" is at [§ 19.2-8](https://law.lis.virginia.gov/vacode/title19.2/chapter1/section19.2-8/).  Section 18-2.422 provides that the offense in question is a class-6 felony.  Nothing at 19.2-8 appears to apply generally to felonies nor specifically to 18.2-422.

Comment: So, are we to understand that Virginia has no statute of limitations at all for felonies, except for those specifically mentioned in 19.2-8?  That seems surprising, and it would be good if we had some more explicit confirmation (e.g. court decisions, law review, etc.).

Comment: Is there perhaps a limit coming from common law?

Comment: @NateEldredge I wouldn't think so, but I certainly do not know.  I encourage anyone who knows more about that than I do to post an answer, which I will upvote.  I will also encourage the asker of the question to accept any such answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that a person work a mask in public and [violated the law](https://law.lis.virginia.gov/vacode/title18.2/chapter9/section18.2-422/), it could have been prosecuted as a class 6 felony. The [statute of limitations](https://codes.findlaw.com/va/title-19-2-criminal-procedure/va-code-sect-19-2-8.html) limits prosecution in cases where the accused has not fled the state. There are specific exclusions surrounding [murder and manslaughter](https://codes.findlaw.com/va/title-19-2-criminal-procedure/va-code-sect-19-2-8-1.html) where there is expressly no limit. Otherwise, the limit is between 1 year and 5 years, depending on the specific crime committed. There is no provision limiting prosecution for rape, robbery, or mask-wearing.

Comment: the law says "or upon any **private** property in this Commonwealth without first having obtained from the owner or tenant thereof consent to do so in writing"

Comment: @DavePhD so someone attending a costume party without a written invitation could presumably be prosecuted.  But those with written invitations would have a defense.

Comment: Yes, it is not clear whether there was a crime in the first place in the current-news context and we're not naming names, so since this is not about a specific incident, this is about whether prosecution is still possible.